# Multipart Download from S3 Bucket using Java

Tags: java, database, multithreading, amazon-s3

We are developing an app which requires multipart download from S3 bucket. The problem is that we require control of the threads which are downloading the file as we have to write data to our DB on the fly(without stitching the file after download) . We want to use multiple threads while writing to the DB and for this we require to download the data from S3 in chunks(which should be valid objects ) and uploading it to our DataBase.

Comment: What you're asking for is not clear. Also, please explain what you've tried so far.

Comment: Since S3 [supports](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectGET.html) HTTP `Range:` requests, the high-level task is simple:  Send a `HEAD` request to learn the object's size (if you don't already know it), then decide where you want the boundaries to be, then  generate signed URLs for each part, and use the user-agent of your choice to fetch them, in threads you control.  It isn't clear what you're asking.